# Function click with buttons in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm loading a table with DataTables. In each row I create a button to click, and the value automatically insert into an input in the opener windows. The function I use is this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      window.opener.document.getElementById('cliente-nombre').value = id;
      window.parent.close();
});
```

The function is not working with the buttons loaded in the datatable. If I create a button which loads with the page (not when the page is fully loaded) it works without problem.

I suppose this doesn't work because they are created when the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with elements loaded in after page load, delegate the event handler via [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to a parent element to ensure they respond to the click.

> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Here I use the `document` object:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  window.opener.document.getElementById('cliente-nombre').value = id;
  window.parent.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a [`$(document).ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). This will wait for the page to load before running the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
          var id = $(this).val();
          window.opener.document.getElementById('cliente-nombre').value = id;
          window.parent.close();
    });
});
```

That way your buttons will be on the DOM before attaching the click handler.